# Finding the longest overlapping period

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, interval

I have a list of records containing `Id, DateFrom, DateTo`. For the sake of this question we can use this one:

```
List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)> data = new List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)>
        {
            (1, new DateTime(2012, 5, 16), new DateTime(2018, 1, 25)),
            (2, new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), new DateTime(2011, 4, 27)),
            (3, new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), new DateTime(2016, 4, 27)),
            (4, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 3)),
        };
```

In my real case the List could be a lot bigger, for now I assume that there is only one entry for a certain `Id`.

The task is to find the two records that has the longest time overlap and to return the ids and the number of days overlapped.

Which in this sample case means that these should be records 1 and 3, because 2 is not overlapping with anyone, and 4 overlaps for shorter time.

My implementation of this is the following:

```
    public (int, int, int) GetLongestElapsedPeriod(List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)> periods)
    {
        int firstId = -1;
        int secondId = -1;
        int periodInDays = 0;

        foreach (var period in periods)
        {
            var Id = period.Item1;
            var dateFrom = period.Item2;
            var dateTo = period.Item3;

            for (int i = 0; i < periods.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Id != periods[i].Item1)
                {
                    var tempId = periods[i].Item1;
                    var tempDateFrom = periods[i].Item2;
                    var tempDateTo = periods[i].Item3;

                    if (tempDateFrom < dateTo && tempDateTo > dateFrom)
                    {
                        DateTime commonStartingDate = tempDateFrom > dateFrom ? tempDateFrom : dateFrom;
                        DateTime commonEndDate = tempDateTo > dateTo ? dateTo : tempDateTo;

                        var elapsedPeriod = commonEndDate - commonStartingDate;

                        if ((int)elapsedPeriod.TotalDays > periodInDays)
                        {
                            periodInDays = (int)elapsedPeriod.TotalDays;
                            firstId = Id;
                            secondId = tempId;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (firstId, secondId, periodInDays);
    }
```

But I think this way is not very efficient and I'm looking for ideas to optimize this logic. Also, I suspect that this is variation of some more general algorithmic problem.

Comment: Sort them by `Item2` perhaps?

Comment: @vnp Yes, it seems that sorting by date can reduce the overall complexity but I would like to see concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a c# programmer.

Firstly, you use a `for each` and a nested `for` loop, but both of these are iterating through the same `List`. For consistency (and for the next comment to make sense), I suggest that you use `for` loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < periods.Count; i++)
```

You could start `i` not from 0. but from your `current location + 1` in the outer loop. The logic behind this is that you have already compared the pairs of periods previous to this - no need to double handle. Hence why using similar `for` loops will make this easier - you will be counting where you are in the `List` in the outer loop.

Making this small change means that `if (Id != periods[i].Item1` is no longer needed - reducing one nesting level in the code.

As a 'meaningful name thing', I would call `commonStartingDate` and `commonEndDate` `overlapStart` and `overlapEnd` respectively - this is more descriptive of what you mean. 
`overlapStart = max(period1.Start, period2.Start) 
overlapEnd = min(period1.End,period2.End)`

Error checking: check that `Item2` is always less than `Item3` (and fix if not), otherwise your logic will be broken.

You could simplify `var elapsedPeriod = commonEndDate - commonStartingDate` and the following code by using:

```
int elapsedPeriod = (int)(commonEndDate - commonStartingDate).TotalDays
```

May not look simpler above, but in the next block:

```
                if (elapsedPeriod > periodInDays)
                {
                    periodInDays = elapsedPeriod;
                    firstId = Id;
                    secondId = tempId;
```

You don't use `elapsedPeriod` for anything else.

The main logic is good - I remember having to solve this problem 25 years ago when developing an accommodation booking database.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I will most certainly keep in mind your recommendations when I refactor my code. The reason why I won't accept it just yet is because I am also looking for performance optimization suggestions. The nested for-loops makes the complexity too big and I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: @Leron: A double `for` is not excessively complex for the posed problem. You're already nesting a `for` in a `foreach`, so I don't quite see how this answer would be more complex than your solution. Also, just to make sure in case that's what you meant with your comment, code complexity and application performance are not related to each other. Simple code can have a slow performance, complex code can run very efficiently.

Comment: @Flater You are correct, and maybe my comment wasn't clear enough. I don't mean that `AJD` answer has some additional performance issue. As you pointed out, both mine idea, and what `AJD` suggest is relaying on nested for loops which makes the complexity `n * n` and even though I am not too much into algorithms I know that in general this is not that great and usually there's a way to optimize such code. As `vnp` commented in the original post, ordering by dates may be the key to reduce the complexity. From what I am trying right now, it seems it's possible to have only one for loop.

Comment: And for this choice to use `foreach` and then `for` I will most certainly follow the recommendations of `AJD` and refactor my code. But essentially in terms of faster execution changing the `foreach` with `for` won't help a lot. As he mentioned I will be able to avoid the `if` check but that's about it.

Comment: @Leron: I'm not convinced you can compare every element to every other element with a single for loop (unless you mean to obfuscate the second loop, e.g. LINQ or convoluted preprocessing of data). The first loop defines the left operand for comparison, the second loop defines the right operand for comparison. A single loop can't define both operands at the same time. You're not comparing the items themselves (which could be simplified by ordering and keeping track of the highest/lowest encountered value), but rather the overlap between two items, which must be calculated first.

Comment: @Flater Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312714/finding-maximum-overlapping-interval-pair-in-onlogn  The original code didn't work for me, but I used the idea and now I have a version which seems to work but I will either make another post just to be sure it's really working or spend more time investigating myself.

Comment: @leron Your performance improvement comes from the refactoring of the second loop. Instead of starting from the beginning each time, it starts from a position that is determined from the first loop. If you are only checking a few time periods you won't notice too much - but if you are checking thousands then this will start to make a big improvement. Cheers.